# jQuery cookie expiring every page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create a cookie policy where when the button is click, it doesn't display for 30 days, however when the button is clicked it shows again if you refresh the page or change page.

code is below:

obviously I've added in jQuery at the bottom of the page

```
<div class="cookie-message" id="cookie_banner">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>This site uses cookies</h3>
      <br>
      <p>We use cookies to ensure the functionality and performance of the website. We also like to use analytics cookies to monitor and analyse the use of our website. If you are happy with this, click ‘Accept and Continue’ below or view our <a href="/cookie-policy" class="underline">cookie policy</a> for more information.</p>
      <button id="close_cookie_banner"  class="btn btn-custom btn-animate btn-pink"><i class="icon-owia-kokroko"></i> Accept and continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>







jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                let COOKIE_NAME = "divine_cookie_policy";

                if ((getCookie(COOKIE_NAME) === "ACCEPTED")){
                  // Cookie has been set -> Don't show banner
                } else {
                  // No cookie has been set -> show cookie banner
                  openCookieBanner();
                }

                $('#close_cookie_banner').on("click", function (event) {
                  event.stopPropagation();

                  closeCookieBanner();
                });

                /**
                 * openCookieBanner()
                 *
                 * Opens the cookie banner
                 */
                function openCookieBanner () {
                  $('#cookie_banner').css({
                    display: "block"
                  });
                } // END openCookieBanner()

                /**
                 * closeCookieBanner()
                 *
                 * Closes the cookie banner
                 */
                function closeCookieBanner () {
                  // Prep the date.
                  var interval = 30;

                  var date = new Date();
                  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (interval*24*60*60*1000));
                  var expires = "expires="+ date.toUTCString();

                  document.cookie = COOKIE_NAME + "=" + "ACCEPTED" + ";" + expires + ";";

                  // Close the banner
                  $('#cookie_banner').css({
                    display: "none"
                  });
                } // END openCookieBanner()

                function getCookie(cname) {
                  var name = cname + "=";
                  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                      c = c.substring(1);
                    }
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                    }
                  }
                  return "";
                }
              }(jQuery));
```

not really sure what else to try

any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried a simple `console.log(getCookie(COOKIE_NAME))` to see what is being returned? It might help narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: Yea so I can see its being returned in google console, however when I refresh I see the cookie for a split second then it vanishes and the div appears